# How to return XML from .Net 5.0 API?

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

In my Startup CS but when I'm using postman with application/xml set in headers, I still get JSON.
I've even added

```cs
services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
    });
```

but it has changed nothing....

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you could return xml format data.

The first way:

You can set `Accept` header to `application/xml` in Postman:

Note:  The headers below(`Host`, `User-Agent` and so on) are all generated automatically by Postman, just change Accept header.

[image]

The second way:

You could add `[Produces("application/xml")]` attribute on your action.

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{...}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```